# Closing a ModelPopup after sending a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I'm looking for a certain behaviour where a ModalPopup suggests a (business-rule driven) file name for a file to download.

[image]

If the user clicks OK, the file is downloaded, and the popup should close. Cancel just closes it. This is all driven by code behind:

```
protected void ExportPromptOkButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = MapPath(ExportPromptPanelFileName.Text);
    WriteExport(path);
    ExportPromptModalPopupExtender.Hide();
    this.SendFile(path, "text/plain");
}

//...

public static void SendFile(this Page webPage, string filepath, string contenttype)
{
    webPage.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filepath));
    webPage.Response.ContentType = contenttype;
    webPage.Response.WriteFile(filepath);;
    webPage.Response.End();
}
```

The problem is that `Response.End();` kills all action (well, as it should), so the modal window itself doesn't close.

**What would be the right approach?** I was thinking of using an iframe and calling its `Response` to send the file, but I'd like to confirm if this is appropriate or if there is something better.

ASPX declaration:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender 
    runat="server" 
    ID="ExportPromptModalPopupExtender" 
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    TargetControlID="ExportButton" 
    PopupControlID="ExportPromptPanel" 
    PopupDragHandleControlID="ExportPromptPanelHeader"
    CancelControlID="ExportPromptCancelButton"
    Drag="true">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="ExportPromptPanel" runat="server" CssClass="popupConfirmation" style="display: none;">
    <div class="popupContainer" style="width:300px">
        <div class="popupHeader" id="ExportPromptPanelHeader">
            <div class="popupHeaderLeft">Export</div><div class="popupHeaderRight"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="popupBody">Export under the following name:<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="ExportPromptPanelFileName" runat="server" MaxLength="60" Width="230px"></asp:TextBox></div><div class="popupButtons">
            <asp:Button ID="ExportPromptOkButton" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="ExportPromptOkButton_Clicked" />
            <asp:Button ID="ExportPromptCancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `OkControlID` property of extender to hide popup on **Ok** button click and `OnOkScript` property for custom javascript function which will force postback from Ok button (modal popup extender prevents postback from Ok and Cancel controls).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doExport() {
        __doPostBack("<%= ExportPromptOkButton.UniqueID %>", "");
    }
</script>


<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender
    runat="server"
    ID="ExportPromptModalPopupExtender"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    TargetControlID="ExportButton"
    PopupControlID="ExportPromptPanel"
    PopupDragHandleControlID="ExportPromptPanelHeader"
    CancelControlID="ExportPromptCancelButton"
    OkControlID="ExportPromptOkButton"
    OnOkScript="doExport"
    Drag="true">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a seprate http handler to process the request
In Modal Popup call the HTTP HANDLER as shown

in ModalPopup :

```
protected void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Handler1.ashx", true);
    }
```

in Handler1.ashx

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd-ms.excel";
        context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;Filename=test.xls");
        context.Response.WriteFile(filepath);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I'm reading about it now. I see you might be conflicted over using `context` or `webPage`. I figured it out, I'm adding the file path to the url.

Comment: yeah sorry it should be context.response.write(file);

Comment: Hmm, something's not right. The modal still doesn't close. Same behaviour as before.

Comment: No dice, all calls after Flush (or End) are not made, and calling Hide() before just doesn't make the modal close.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with ModalPopupExtender.hide() !